# Editing the Border of a BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, methods, bufferedimage

I am trying to create a method that will add a border to a BufferedImage where both border thickness and border color can be configurable by the parameters of the method.

Border thickness will be a non-negative integer (0, 1, 2, etc.) and corresponds to how many pixels thick the border should be on all four sides inside the perimeter of the image.

Border color is a length 3 integer array, corresponding to the RGB color value that the border should be.

This is the original image: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdvs7.png)

This is what the image should look like with a border of thickness 10 and RGB values 235, 64, 52: [resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV8kh.png)

This is the code I have but I keep running into an out-of-bounds error. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VthKA.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help. I also realize I can use Java's graphics tools to edit on top of the image but I'm trying to edit the image itself and not create any kind of overlays.

```
public static void applyBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, int[] borderColor) {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int borderRgb = (borderColor[0] << 16) | (borderColor[1] << 8) | borderColor[2];

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < borderThickness; y++) {
        img.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Top border
        img.setRGB(x, img.getHeight() - 1 - y, borderRgb); // Bottom border
      }
    }

    for (int y = borderThickness; y < img.getHeight() - borderThickness; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < borderThickness; x++) {
        img.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Left border
        img.setRGB(img.getWidth() - 1 - x, y, borderRgb); // Right border
      }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        img.setRGB(x + borderThickness, y + borderThickness, img.getRGB(x, y));
      }
    }
  }
```

This is how I am calling the method in the main class:

```
int borderThickness = 10;
int[] borderColor = {255, 0, 0};
applyBorder(img, borderThickness, borderColor);
File fileBorder = new File("dog_border.png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", fileBorder);
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Hints: 1) `BufferedImage` has a [`setRGB()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,int,int)) method, no need to get the pixels; 2) it also has a [`getGraphics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics()) which returns a `Graphics` used to *paint* onto the image, the preferred way to *edit* an image

Comment: @dan1st Technically nothing. I just don't know what to do next as far as the editing of the pixels goes

Comment: You can more simply just use the Graphics object from a BufferedImage  to draw the border

Comment: I wonder what the last nested `for` loops are intended for? The sample images included in this question show the border just draw over the image, not around it (image size not changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you might do this, personally I might consider making use of `Area`, as it allows you to `subtract` (or `add`) shapes together, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static BufferedImage applyBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, Color borderColor) {
        if (borderThickness * 2 > img.getWidth() || borderThickness * 2 > img.getHeight()) {
            return null;
        }
        Area border = new Area(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        border.subtract(new Area(new Rectangle(
                borderThickness, 
                borderThickness, 
                img.getWidth() - (borderThickness * 2), 
                img.getHeight() - (borderThickness * 2)
        )));
        BufferedImage targetImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
        Graphics2D g2d = targetImg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.setColor(borderColor);
        g2d.fill(border);
        g2d.dispose();
        return targetImg;
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            BufferedImage master = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/MegaTokyo.png"));
            BufferedImage bordered = applyBorder(master, 10, Color.RED);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

            add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(master)));
            add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bordered)));
        }
    }
}
```

You're probably scratching your head trying to figure out why this would be of benefit.

Consider for a second, what if you wanted the border to have a rounded inner edge!

Well, that's pretty easy to achieve, simply modify the `applyBorder` method to subtract a different shape, for example...

```
border.subtract(new Area(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(
        borderThickness, 
        borderThickness, 
        img.getWidth() - (borderThickness * 2), 
        img.getHeight() - (borderThickness * 2),
        32,
        32
)));
```

which generates...

[image]

You could also make use of the existing `Border` API if you really wanted to.

## The "problem"...

The reason you're getting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is because the code which, I think, for some reason I don't understand, fills the image with the  pixels of the image...I'm assuming you're trying to "insert" the image into the border, rather then having the border drawn on top of the image???

Anyway, your problem is here...

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x + borderThickness, y + borderThickness, img.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }
```

When `x` is `width - 1`, you're then adding `borderThickness` to it, which attempts to place a pixel outside of the image range.  Same thing goes for `y` position.

Assuming you want to add the border around the image, as apposed to adding the border over the image, you need to modify your code to create a new image which is large enough to contain the original image and the border, for example...

[image]

```
public static BufferedImage applySlowBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, Color borderColor) {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int borderRgb = borderColor.getRGB();//(borderColor[0] << 16) | (borderColor[1] << 8) | borderColor[2];
    
    BufferedImage targetImg = new BufferedImage(
            img.getWidth() + (borderThickness * 2), 
            img.getHeight() + (borderThickness * 2), 
            img.getType()
    );

    for (int x = 0; x < targetImg.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < borderThickness; y++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Top border
            targetImg.setRGB(x, targetImg.getHeight() - 1 - y, borderRgb); // Bottom border
        }
    }

    for (int y = borderThickness; y < targetImg.getHeight() - borderThickness; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < borderThickness; x++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Left border
            targetImg.setRGB(targetImg.getWidth() - 1 - x, y, borderRgb); // Right border
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x + borderThickness, y + borderThickness, img.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }
    return targetImg;
}
```

If, however, you want to have the border painted over the image, then you need to paint the original image first, for example...

[image]

```
public static BufferedImage applySlowBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, Color borderColor) {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int borderRgb = borderColor.getRGB();//(borderColor[0] << 16) | (borderColor[1] << 8) | borderColor[2];
    
    BufferedImage targetImg = new BufferedImage(
            img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight(),
            img.getType()
    );

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x, y, img.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < targetImg.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < borderThickness; y++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Top border
            targetImg.setRGB(x, targetImg.getHeight() - 1 - y, borderRgb); // Bottom border
        }
    }

    for (int y = borderThickness; y < targetImg.getHeight() - borderThickness; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < borderThickness; x++) {
            targetImg.setRGB(x, y, borderRgb); // Left border
            targetImg.setRGB(targetImg.getWidth() - 1 - x, y, borderRgb); // Right border
        }
    }
    return targetImg;
}
```

*fyi: Using my super accurate, scientific measurement tools (insert sarcasm ), the `Graphics2D` approach is about 10 milliseconds faster then the `get/setRGB` approach - while not a massive difference, the size of the image will have an increasingly large impact on these results - for example, using a 1920x1080 source image, the `Graphics2D` approach took about 9 milliseconds, where as your code took about 203 milliseconds - again, these are "observational" differences, but `get/setRGB` is known for been slow*

Comment: Mr. FancyRoundedBorders. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Have cats, will skin 

Comment: What is the meaning of `rows: -1` in `new GridLayout(-1, 2)` ? Shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: @user85421 Same thing :P

Comment: but not as documented... and the non-public javadoc of `rows` even states: "*This should be a non negative integer*" (but kind of a *backdoor* since it only throws an IllegalArgument `if ((rows == 0) && (cols == 0))` [Java 22])

Comment: @user85421 Seems to work just fine otherwise

Comment: I was trying to accomplish the second example. That is, being able to add the border over the image rather than around the image. Thank you for your time and examples, they really helped!

Comment: @user85421 So I dug into the implementation of `GridLayout` and the code looks for `ncols` or `nrows` which are `> 0`, which explains why `-1` works ... because the documentation is always so super accurate 

Comment: *let's hope* it doesn't get changed in some future version... at least the *public* javadoc does not explicitly require it to be non negative; maybe considered implicit, since hard to have a negative number of columns/rows.

Comment: @user85421 So hard to have `0` 

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a border around an image using the `Graphics`/`Graphics2D` object from a `BufferedImage`. For example:

```
public BufferedImage addBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, Color borderColor) {
    if (img == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("img cannot be null");
    }
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    // create a new image, the same size as the old
    BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, img.getType());

    // extract the Graphics2D object
    Graphics2D g = newImg.createGraphics();

    // draw the original image with it
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    // then draw the border 
    g.setColor(borderColor);
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(borderThickness));
    g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // conserve resources
    g.dispose();

    return newImg;
}
```

Or using an int array:

```
public BufferedImage addBorder(BufferedImage img, int borderThickness, int[] borderColor) {
    if (img == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("img cannot be null");
    }
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    // create a new image, the same size as the old
    BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, img.getType());

    // extract the Graphics2D object
    Graphics2D g = newImg.createGraphics();

    // draw the original image with it
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    // then draw the border
    g.setColor(new Color(borderColor[0], borderColor[1], borderColor[2]));
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(borderThickness));
    g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // conserve resources
    g.dispose();

    return newImg;
}
```

And the code can be tested as so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String urlPath = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdvs7.png";
    URL url = null;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlPath);
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    AddBorder addBorder = new AddBorder();
    BufferedImage newImg = addBorder.addBorder(img, 20, Color.BLUE);

    // display original image
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(img);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon1);

    // display the image
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(newImg);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Although I am trying to avoid using Graphics2D

Comment: @KajSech Why (avoid `Graphics2D`)?  It provides an easy to use abstraction layer, which is much simpler and generally faster then trying to modify the raster data

Comment: this code is painting only half of the thickness inside the image, eventually missing one pixel on right and bottom sides (try `thickness=1`) - the coordinates/sizes for `drawRect` must be adjusted (or the Stroke doubled.)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just want to learn how to edit the RGB values of the pixels of the array without painting over them

Comment: @KajSech *"edit the RGB values of the pixels of the array without painting over them"* - well `setRGB` is "painting" over the pixel ... or at least replacing it.  Honestly I think you're missing an opportunity to learn the power of the `Graphics` API as it applies to many other areas, not just images. If your interested in "more advance" technquies, I would recommend [JH Labs](http://www.jhlabs.com/index.html), a rather interesting read